# PYTHON - How to scrape stock "Key Data" from MarketWatch.com where the data is dynamically produced. Finding the data request call?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a sample/personal project I am working on that would retrieve stock data from a website such as market watch once per day for a specific stock and then compare the data to other sites such as google finance/yahoo finance/reuters and test for accuracy.

I am stuck on retrieving the data from MarketWatch. It seems that the "Key Data" I am looking for (can be found by going to: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl) is being produced dynamically because when I programmatically collect the web-page HTML it barely contains any data compared to visiting the website in a browser.

I've tried opening the developer console in my browser and looking for AJAX calls, but have not been successful in finding any. I could easily skip collecting data from MarketWatch and move on, but I'm look at this as a challenge to improve my l33t skillz in programming.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I would be interested in finding a way to get the right call for the data request or perhaps it only displays the data when there is a certain value being sent in the header? Those were my ideas. I am using Python and Beautiful Soup to parse any data.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW INFORMATION IN RESPONSE TO OPS COMMENT**

My mistake! Try something like this instead. The key is in getting the Cookie and making sure it is in your get request headers. You can get this Cookie manually from your web browser's developer network tab while on that marketwatch page. Just find the get request for the webpage from there, get into the request headers and copy/paste the Cookie into your code. It's a super long string. You will need it before the server returns the full webpage.

**I am sure there is a way to get this cookie via code from marketwatch.com before making the actual get request that contains your data. I can try to figure that out too if needed.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl'
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
                               "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                               "Cookie": "refresh=on; letsGetMikey=enabled; "
                                         "MicrosoftApplicationsTelemetryDeviceId=46fa0ca5-2561-7fe5-fd62-5b632398b7f4; "
                                         "MicrosoftApplicationsTelemetryFirstLaunchTime=1534997155966; "
                                         "pf_ffm=9bffce74bd493d996d1ae35769695510; "
                                         "mw_loc=%7B%22country%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22TX%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22"
                                         "PLANO%22%2C%22county%22%3A%5B%22COLLIN%22%5D%2C%22continent%22%3A%22NA%22%7D; "
                                         "seenads=0; fullcss-quote=quote-85dcea2e5c.min.css; "
                                         "utag_main=v_id:016564f545b40022de054359ac4403044003000900bd0$_sn:1$_ss:0$_st:"
                                         "1534999294146$ses_id:1534997120440%3Bexp-session$_pn:2%3Bexp-session$"
                                         "_prevpage:MW_Quote_Page%3Bexp-1535001094154$vapi_domain:marketwatch.com; "
                                         "AMCV_CB68E4BA55144CAA0A4C98A5%40AdobeOrg=-1891778711%7CMCIDTS%7C17767%7CMCMID"
                                         "%7C01084133064198290912411637324115388504%7CMCAAMLH-1535601937%7C9%7CMCAAMB"
                                         "-1535601937%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT"
                                         "-1535004337s%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-17774%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C2.4.0"
                                         "; icons-loaded=true; AMCVS_CB68E4BA55144CAA0A4C98A5%40AdobeOrg=1; __gads=ID="
                                         "c71aa1564ab44c97:T=1534997138:S=ALNI_Mbyv41MxhHTThfXFxMGtCFVyzsQaQ; "
                                         "vidoraUserId=agqj4i6ugtd359uhgkfl761k4uu55g; __qca=P0-1349423161-15349971262"
                                         "36; _ncg_sp_ses.f57d=*; _ncg_sp_id.f57d=b8b37d7b-2719-4a9c-baf9-3695f9deb20"
                                         "8.1534997155.1.1534997520.1534997155.9a279294-1ff6-449e-a605-29c39215cfb4;"
                                         " _ncg_id_=b8b37d7b-2719-4a9c-baf9-3695f9deb208; _ncg_g_id_=bd42bc08-4ebd-"
                                         "44a1-8e7a-6e1c3eaac874; _parsely_visitor={%22id%22:%2211d7400c-c4f5-4322-"
                                         "b109-0b01a21a74f2%22%2C%22session_count%22:1%2C%22last_session_"
                                         "ts%22:1534997165510}; _parsely_session={%22sid%22:1%2C%22surl%22:"
                                         "%22https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl%22%2C%22sref%22:"
                                         "%22%22%2C%22sts%22:1534997165510%2C%22slts%22:0}; "
                                         "s_ppvl=MW_Quote_Page%2C27%2C27%2C945%2C1076%2C945%2C1920%2C1080%2C1%2CP;"
                                         " s_ppv=MW_Quote_Page%2C23%2C23%2C945%2C1076%2C945%2C1920%2C1080%2C1%2CP;"
                                         " s_cc=true; cX_P=jl61ojfsquomne4l; usr_bkt=63L1D4y2F9; cX_S=jl61ojgcxgxachax;"
                                         " cX_G=cx%3A12c0heqgxq7ug25eyhsfbg5iro%3A3qlznewunoji0; "
                                         "recentqsmkii=Stock-US-AAPL; __utma=246750488.1666075546.1534997552."
                                         "1534997552.1534997552.1; __utmb=246750488.1.9.1534997559734; "
                                         "__utmc=246750488; __utmz=246750488.1534997552.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)"
                                         "|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)"})
print(r)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
key_data = soup.find_all('li', class_="kv__item")
# Key Data Field Names
print(soup.find_all('small', class_="kv__label"))
# Key Data Field Values
print(soup.find_all('span', class_="kv__primary"))
```

Response:

```
<Response [200]>
[<small class="kv__label">Open</small>, <small class="kv__label">Day Range</small>, <small class="kv__label">52 Week Range</small>, <small class="kv__label">Market Cap</small>, <small class="kv__label">Shares Outstanding</small>, <small class="kv__label">Public Float</small>, <small class="kv__label">Beta</small>, <small class="kv__label">Rev. per Employee</small>, <small class="kv__label">P/E Ratio</small>, <small class="kv__label">EPS</small>, <small class="kv__label">Yield</small>, <small class="kv__label">Dividend</small>, <small class="kv__label">Ex-Dividend Date</small>, <small class="kv__label">Short Interest</small>, <small class="kv__label">% of Float Shorted</small>, <small class="kv__label">Average Volume</small>]
[<span class="kv__value kv__primary ">$214.10</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">213.84 - 216.36</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">149.16 - 219.18</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">$1.04T</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">4.83B</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">4.82B</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">1.02</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">$2.08M</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">19.50</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">$11.03</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">1.36%</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">$0.73</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">Aug 10, 2018</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">37.27M</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">0.77%</span>, <span class="kv__value kv__primary ">24.1M</span>]
```

**END NEW INFORMATION**

If you want to get the daily stock price data from that marketwatch page's chart, something like this will work. They do have an API Route. **You may need to update the EntitlementToken for this to work**:

```
import requests
import json

# May need to update the EntitlementToken. To do so go to https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl,
#  watch network connections, find the api call and parse out the token
# If token does not match. api call will return a 400

req_url = 'https://api-secure.wsj.net/api/michelangelo/timeseries/history?json={"Step":"PT1M","TimeFrame":"D1",' \
          '"EntitlementToken":"cecc4267a0194af89ca343805a3e57af","IncludeMockTick":true,"FilterNullSlots":false,' \
          '"FilterClosedPoints":true,"IncludeClosedSlots":false,"IncludeOfficialClose":true,"InjectOpen":false,' \
          '"ShowPreMarket":false,"ShowAfterHours":false,"UseExtendedTimeFrame":false,"WantPriorClose":true,' \
          '"IncludeCurrentQuotes":false,"ResetTodaysAfterHoursPercentChange":false,' \
          '"Series":[{"Key":"STOCK/US/XNAS/AAPL","Dialect":"Charting","Kind":"Ticker","SeriesId":"s1",' \
          '"DataTypes":["Last"],"Indicators":[{"Parameters":[{"Name":"ShowOpen"},{"Name":"ShowHigh"},' \
          '{"Name":"ShowLow"},{"Name":"ShowPriorClose","Value":true},{"Name":"Show52WeekHigh"},' \
          '{"Name":"Show52WeekLow"}],"Kind":"OpenHighLowLines","SeriesId":"i2"}]}]}&ckey=cecc4267a0'

r = requests.get(req_url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
                                   "Content-Type": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
                                   "Dylan2010.EntitlementToken": "cecc4267a0194af89ca343805a3e57af"})
# Full Return
print(r)

# Stock UNIX Dates
print(json.loads(r.content)['TimeInfo']['Ticks'])

# Stock Prices
print(json.loads(r.content)['Series'][0]['DataPoints'])
```

Which will print out the following data (**This is only a sample of the first 5 records of the return**):

```
<Response [200]>
# Unix Datetime Stamps
[1534944600000, 1534944660000, 1534944720000, 1534944780000, 1534944840000]
# AAPL Prices
[[214.9001], [214.81], [214.84], [215.31], [215.2]]
```

**If you need access to free financial data on a regular basis I'd highly recommend using YahooFinancials**

https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials

**Install:**

```
$ pip install yahoofinancials
```

**Usage Example:**

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

tech_stocks = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'INTC']
yahoo_financials_tech = YahooFinancials(tech_stocks)
print(yahoo_financials_tech.get_historical_price_data("2018-08-01", "2018-08-10", "weekly"))
```

**Results:**

```
   {
        "AAPL": {
            "currency": "USD", 
            "eventsData": {
                "dividends": {
                    "2018-08-06": {
                        "amount": 0.73, 
                        "date": 1533907800, 
                        "formatted_date": "2018-08-10"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "firstTradeDate": {
                "date": 345459600, 
                "formatted_date": "1980-12-12"
            }, 
            "instrumentType": "EQUITY", 
            "prices": [
                {
                    "adjclose": 207.2631072998047, 
                    "close": 207.99000549316406, 
                    "date": 1532923200, 
                    "formatted_date": "2018-07-30", 
                    "high": 208.74000549316406, 
                    "low": 197.30999755859375, 
                    "open": 199.1300048828125, 
                    "volume": 163787100
                }, 
                {
                    "adjclose": 206.80471801757812, 
                    "close": 207.52999877929688, 
                    "date": 1533528000, 
                    "formatted_date": "2018-08-06", 
                    "high": 209.77999877929688, 
                    "low": 204.52000427246094, 
                    "open": 208.0, 
                    "volume": 121618700
                }
            ], 
            "timeZone": {
                "gmtOffset": -14400
            }
        }, 
        "INTC": {
            "currency": "USD", 
            "eventsData": {
                "dividends": {
                    "2018-08-06": {
                        "amount": 0.3, 
                        "date": 1533562200, 
                        "formatted_date": "2018-08-06"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "firstTradeDate": {
                "date": 322131600, 
                "formatted_date": "1980-03-17"
            }, 
            "instrumentType": "EQUITY", 
            "prices": [
                {
                    "adjclose": 49.33000183105469, 
                    "close": 49.630001068115234, 
                    "date": 1532923200, 
                    "formatted_date": "2018-07-30", 
                    "high": 49.779998779296875, 
                    "low": 48.0, 
                    "open": 48.060001373291016, 
                    "volume": 76521400
                }, 
                {
                    "adjclose": 48.55471420288086, 
                    "close": 48.849998474121094, 
                    "date": 1533528000, 
                    "formatted_date": "2018-08-06", 
                    "high": 50.599998474121094, 
                    "low": 48.29999923706055, 
                    "open": 48.77000045776367, 
                    "volume": 129482900
                }
            ], 
            "timeZone": {
                "gmtOffset": -14400
            }
        }, 
        "MSFT": {
            "currency": "USD", 
            "eventsData": {}, 
            "firstTradeDate": {
                "date": 511088400, 
                "formatted_date": "1986-03-13"
            }, 
            "instrumentType": "EQUITY", 
            "prices": [
                {
                    "adjclose": 107.62582397460938, 
                    "close": 108.04000091552734, 
                    "date": 1532923200, 
                    "formatted_date": "2018-07-30", 
                    "high": 108.08999633789062, 
                    "low": 104.83999633789062, 
                    "open": 106.02999877929688, 
                    "volume": 68392600
                }, 
                {
                    "adjclose": 108.58214569091797, 
                    "close": 109.0, 
                    "date": 1533528000, 
                    "formatted_date": "2018-08-06", 
                    "high": 110.16000366210938, 
                    "low": 107.55999755859375, 
                    "open": 108.12000274658203, 
                    "volume": 83677700
                }
            ], 
            "timeZone": {
                "gmtOffset": -14400
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is great, however, it doesn't help me with my question. The data I was looking for was going to be in the "Key Data" section on MarketWatch (contains values such as EPS, Divs, Day Highs/Lows, Etc). Not only would I like to get this data I would like to know HOW I could retrieve it. Your explanation on getting historical data was very good, but I cannot apply it to my problem, or at least I don't think. Thank you very much for putting the effort into your answer, it is a great one, but not 100% what I am looking for.

Comment: My mistake! I went ahead and updated to my answer with a way to get the data you requested. The request headers for the marketwatch webpage need a valid Cookie string from the site to work. You can get this cookie either manually or via code if you make a prior request to get the cookie before making the actual request for the webpage's html.

Comment: Seems like we are getting close, but I still can't get the full page HTML to load. I'm currently loading my cookie (pulled from developer tools tab) into my python request. I even tried with your cookie. I also have the other header keys assigned (User-Agent/Accept). Have you been able to retrieve the full page HTML on your end with your assigned cookie?

Comment: I got it to work. So... the cookie is also assigned to the User-Agent. New User-Agent from Python script = needed new cookie... I used the same User-Agent from my initial request and I was able to get the full page html. I will mark this as correct. Thank you for figuring out the situation.

Comment: Hi one last time, I created a separate question regarding the cookie-auth for this problem. Maybe you can help me solve it, here is the URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027493/python-requests-web-scraping-building-a-cookie-to-be-able-to-view-data-in-a

Comment: Sure. I can look at it this evening when I get done with work. The first avenue I'd take personally would be to find the api call made when initially loading the webpage to see if the cookie is returned in that payload somewhere (prob response headers or something) for upstream use. The ideal goal would be to get a legit cookie from them vs building a spoof one (one could argue that's now unethical hacking tbh). Absolute worst case scenario for something like this we can just use selenium to get the cookie/scrap if they are strict on web drivers.

Comment: Ok sure. What I meant by cookie-building was that it seems there are a few steps that need to be taken to actually get a legit cookie value. Once you have the cookie you are good to go for every request. I've broken it down as far as I can in the thread I posted. I really appreciate the time you've taken to help me so far, thank you.

Comment: Of course. I know what you meant. The problem isn't that it builds the cookie from a cascade of API calls though. It's some work, but still easy to get around if you just watch and learn the API calls. The problem is the possible ethical issues that come into question if things get a little hacky from our end (such as needing to spoof or fake a host address, referring host address, IP, Private API Key, etc in an API call to get a portion of the cookie we need. It's akin to breaking a locked door open, even if it's weak lock). In those instance's I'd be more comfortable with a web driver.